# mysql follow and retweet-like functionality

Tags: mysql, performance, twitter, group-by, twitter-follow

This is a bit challenging but fun question.
Consider having these tables

**tweets**

```
tweet_id | retweet_of_id | user_id
```

**follow**

```
user_id | followed_user_id
```

So we store each "retweet as a **separate** tweet" pointing to the original tweet's id (`retweet_of_id`). This is because I want to have comments under each one separately.
If something is not a retweet then `retweet_of_id` will be `0`.

How do I retrieve the following using MySQL **efficiently**?

- My own tweets
- All the original tweets (from users that I follow)
- And the **first** retweet (by a user I follow) of a tweet (from a user that I don't follow)

And that the result should a combination of both (in order) just like how twitter does it.
Please consider that there may be 1,000,000 tweets and we only need the most recent ones (e.g.: 10).

---

Here is an **example** (I'm user 1 and I follow user 2 & 3)

```
tweet_id | retweet_of_id | user_id
----------------------------------
    1            0            4          <- EXCLUDE (I don't follow user 4)
    2            0            2          <- INCLUDE (I follow user 2)
    3            0            3          <- INCLUDE (I follow user 3)
    4            1            2          <- INCLUDE (I follow user 2 & first RT)
    5            1            3          <- EXCLUDE (I already have the first RT)
    6            2            3          <- EXCLUDE (I already have the orignal)
    7            0            1          <- INCLUDE (My own tweet)
```

So the final order should be these tweets: `7, 4, 3, 2` *(starting with the most recent)*

Comment: Where you able to figure out the best query for this? I'm kinda facing the same problem too :)

Comment: Yes I posted my solutions in an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it
*(both of these assume that the tweets are ordered by their `tweet_id` ASC)*

**Solution 1** (correct, runs fast)

```
SELECT tweet_id,
FROM tweets 
WHERE user = 1 OR user IN (2,3)  
GROUP BY  IF(retweet_of_id = 0, tweet_id, retweet_of_id)
ORDER BY tweet_id DESC
```

---

**Solution 2** (gives correct results, but it's dog slow for 1,000,000 tweets)

```
SELECT p1.tweet_id FROM tweets p1 
LEFT JOIN tweets p2 
       ON p2.user IN (2,3)
      AND p1.tweet_id > p2.tweet_id
      AND (p1.retweet_of_id = p2.tweet_id 
           OR p1.retweet_of_id AND p1.retweet_of_id = p2.retweet_of_id )
WHERE p2.tweet_id IS NULL
  AND (p1.user = 1 OR p1.user IN (2,3)) 
ORDER BY p1.tweet_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

#### all the original tweets (from users that I follow)

1 users that i follow:

```
select user_id from follow where followed_user_id= MyOwnID
```

2 all the original tweets:

```
select * from tweets where retweed_of_id=0
```

both combined:

```
select * from tweets where retweed_of_id=0 and
user_id in (select user_id from follow where followed_user_id= MyOwnID)
```

that should be it - or did i miss something?

Comment: Yes I know how to get these. The tricky part is the second point about the **first** retweet (by a user I follow) of a tweet (from a user that I don't follow). And that the result should a combined list (in order) with the original tweets. Just like how twitter does it.

Comment: you will need an autoincrement id for that, have to modify my upper example to retweed_of_id<>0 and have to limit the answer to 1 ( so you just get the first re_tweets of users you know). Having another subselect you can limit that to tweets of people you don't know!

Comment: Can you modify your answer so I can see what you mean? I also added an example. Maybe it helps.